# Андроид передача файла по сети

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. Опыта с андроидом нет, поэтому получил вот такую проблему, которую никак не могу решить.

**Проблема** заключается в том что с андроида не получается отправить видео-файл размером 115Мб.

**В чем она выражена:**

Если точнее то из 115Мб уходит на сервер 52Мб и на этом передача прекращается. причем сервер возвращает код=200 и пишет, что принял файл размером 52Мб. Хотя файл размером 60Мб отправляется с приложения - БЕЗ ПРОБЛЕМ!

Ниже приведу пример используемого кода.

```
    private class UploadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<File>> {
    protected List<File> doInBackground(String... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                resultTextView.append("\nuploading started.....");
            }
        });

        for (File file : fileList){
            uploadFile(file);
        }

        return null; //loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<File> list) {
        resultTextView.append("\nUPLOAD -> STATE: " + MultipartUtility.status);
        resultTextView.append("\nUPLOAD -> END");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UPLOAD: -> END", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}




public int uploadFile(File sourceFile) {


    final String fileName = sourceFile.getName();

    HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable;//, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
    long fileSize = sourceFile.length();

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                //+ uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                + sourceFile.getName()
        );

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                resultTextView.append("Source File not exist :"
                        //+uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                        + fileName
                );
            }
        });

        return 0;

    }
    else
    {
        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(360000);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "bearer " + token.getAccess());
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive" );
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data" );
            conn.setRequestProperty("Transfer-Encoding","chunked" );
            conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            //conn.setRequestProperty("file", sourceFile.getPath());
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""
                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd
            );

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                sendBytes = sendBytes + bytesRead;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        sizeTextView.setText("BUFFER-SIZE: " + bufferSize + "\nNAME: " + fileName + "\nSIZE: " + sendBytes);
                    }
                });
            }


            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        resultTextView.append("\nUPLOAD-CODE: " + serverResponseCode);
                        String msg = "\nFile Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                + fileName;

                        resultTextView.append(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    resultTextView.append("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "MalformedURLException",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    resultTextView.append("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload-Exception", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
        android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

При тестировании сервера проблем не выявлено! Этот же метод передачи файла замечательно работает в обычном консольном режиме (бот) при -Xmx10M;

Сервер:

```
@PostMapping("/{id}/file")
public void uploadFile(@PathVariable("id") Request request, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files){
    log.info("==========================================");
    log.info("===uploadFile2:start:" + request.getId());

    if (files.length<1) {
        throw new StorageException("No Files");
    }

    try {

        FileUpload.saveUploadedFiles(Arrays.asList(files), "/request/1266123/");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new StorageException("File upload error", e);
    }

    log.info("Successfully uploaded - " + files.length);

}
```

**Заранее благодарен за ответ.**

PS/ Такое чувство что оно читает с оригинального потока только 52Мб и отправляет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ЭТОТ КОД ПОЛНОСТЬЮ РАБОЧИЙ**. проблема была в самом файле, который как оказалось был битым и весил свои 52Мб